# Laptop crashes the wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, windows-8.1

While trying out a new Asus laptop (with an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265), strange things happen: as soon as I connect to my network, after a few seconds or up to a minute or so, the Internet connection is gone on the whole wifi network. All other devices connected via wifi lose their Internet connection, although they still remain connected to the network.
Devices connected with cables to the same wifi router continue to have access.

After turning the new laptop off, the connection is reestablished only after restarting the router. Turning the new laptop on (or enabling its wifi) again crashes the connection.

I've seen several similar problems, all which were solved, but their solutions don't seem to work for me:

- in one case, a [Lenovo service](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/487016-laptop-crashes-wifi-connection) was causing issues and stopping it solved the problem. In my case, i didn't find any similar programs in my task manager
- in another case, the [driver of a Samsung laptop](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f31/solved-laptop-crashes-my-network-535812.html) was full with bugs, and updating it solved the problem. I installed the latest driver (end of 2014) which I downloaded directly from the manufacturer's website, according to the exact type of my laptop. I have the router for more than 2 years, so a 2014 driver for my laptop shouldn't be too old for it.

Comment: Have you checked for an IP address conflict?

Comment: @DavidPostill : yes, all my devices have different IP addresses, acquired from DHCP. However, even if an IP conflict was causing the problem, it would cause problems only with one other device. Besides the new Asus, I have an old laptop and a phone, and both lose access once I connect with the new laptop.

Comment: Have you tried 1/ resetting your router? 2/ Updating your router firmware?

Comment: @DavidPostill : Yes, I did

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this important information. You can add a "What I've tried/checked" section to your question. From [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask): "if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer."

Comment: Strangely, updating and resetting wasn't enough. My ISP uses a PPPOE connection, and after I erased that from my router and connected again to the ISP, everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Great! You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the firmware of my router, but that alone wasn't enough. My ISP uses a PPPoE connection, and after I erased that from my router and connected again to the ISP, everything seems to work fine.